# Laravel- Due in the next 6 months using Carbon submonths

Tags: laravel, php-carbon

I am trying to relieve data from my database that will only return data that will be due in the next 6 months.

In my controller, this is how I query my database.

```
$critical = infrastructure::where("inf_lifspan",">", Carbon::now()->subMonths(6))->get();
```

The results is shown below.

[image]

Can someone point me in the right direction what I did wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, I got the answer. I just need to change the > sign to < sign.

```
$critical = infrastructure::whereDate('inf_lifspan','<', Carbon::now()->addMonths(6))->get();
```